# Consider a car moving along the x-axis with a varying velocity over time.

Tags: integration

Consider a car moving along the $x$-axis with a varying velocity over time given below:

$$v(t) = e^{t}$$

Determine the distance it has traveled after $2$ seconds.

Comment: I know I have to integrate, but does it make a difference that it moves along x axis? Does it have to do with parametric equations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not matter that it moves along the $x$ axis.  You still have the distance is $\int_0^2v(t)dt$

Comment: Ok cool thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem of $$\int_0^2{v(t)}\mathrm dt = \int_0^2{e^t}\mathrm dt,$$
we first need to know the antiderivative of $e^t$. We know from differential calculus that $$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} \left[e^x\right] = e^x,$$
and thus $$\int_0^2{e^t}\mathrm dt = \left[e^t\right]_0^2 = e^2 - e^0 = e^2 - 1$$